# Magic Sequences of length n

Tags: number, fastest-code, sequence

A magic sequence is a sequence of non-negative integers `x[0..n-1]` such that there are exactly `x[i]` instances of `i`

For instance, 6,2,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0 is a magic sequence since there are 6 0's, 2 1’s, and so on.

Write a function which when given n, outputs all magic sequences of length n

---

The program that can produce the correct output for the highest value of n within 10 seconds win. (All programs are welcome, though)

For example, Alice's program can deal with upto n=15 within 10 seconds while Bob's can deal with upto n=20 within the same time. Bob wins.

Platform: Linux 2.7GHz @ 4 CPUs

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is a great challenge, but you need a winning criterion. For example, you could say that the winner is the shortest program.

Comment: Relevant: [Self-descriptive number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-descriptive_number)

Comment: @Ypnypn thanks I've added the winning criteria

Comment: Sorry, I changed the winning criteria.

Comment: Please don't change the winning criterion after answers have been posted. Also, this was much better as a code golf than as fastest code, at least in my opinion.

Comment: For fastest code, is there a reasonable approach other than enumerating all sequences and checking for magicness?

Comment: @xnor you can start by generating the integer partitions of n and checking if they can be self-descriptive.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Good point, I'm seeing some interesting ways to short-circuit the searches now.

Comment: What's the smallest  `n>5` with a solution not of the form `[n-4, 2, 1, ..., 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`?  I've looked up to `n=20` and not found one, and wondering if I'm making an error.

Comment: Given that xnor has now established that this has a trivial solution, and is therefore not appropriate for fastest code, can we switch it back to code-golf?

Comment: This is not appropriate as [tag:fastest-code] - you're only limited by I/O speed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Python, n≈10<sup>8</sup>

```python
def magic_sequences(n):
    if n==4:
        return (1, 2, 1, 0),(2, 0, 2, 0) 
    elif n==5:
        return (2, 1, 2, 0, 0),
    elif n>=7:
        return (n-4,2,1)+(0,)*(n-7)+(1,0,0,0),
    else:
        return ()
```

This uses the fact, which I'll prove, that the only Magic sequences of length `n` are:

- `[1, 2, 1, 0]` and  `[2, 0, 2, 0]` for `n=4`
- `[2, 1, 2, 0, 0]` for `n=5`
- `[n-4, 2, 1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]` for `n>=7`

So, for `n>=7`, one only needs to return a huge tuple. I can do this for up to roughly `n=10^8` on my laptop, which is likely limited by memory; any more and it freezes up. (Thanks to trichoplax for the idea of using tuples rather than lists.) Or, if one can instead print a dictionary of nonzero entries, `{0:n-4, 1:2, 2:1, (n-4):1}`, one can do this for ginormous `n`.

I prove the uniqueness for `n>=7`; the other ones can be checked by brute force or casework.

The sum of the entries of `l` is the total count of all numbers of the list, which is its length `n`. The list has `l[0]` zeroes, and so `n-l[0]` nonzero entries. But by definition `l[0]` must be nonzero or we get a contradiction, and each of the other nonzero entries is at least 1. This already accounts for a sum of `l[0] + (n-l[0]-1)*1 = n-1` out of the overall sum of `n`. So not counting `l[0]`, there can be at most one 2 and no entry bigger than 2.

But that means the only nonzero entries are `l[0], l[1], l[2], and l[l[0]]`, whose values are at most `l[0]` and a permutation of `1,1,2`, which gives a maximum sum of `l[0]+4`. Since this sum is `n`, which is at least 7, we have `l[0]>=3`, and so `l[l[0]]=1`. Now, there's at least one `1`, which means `l[1]>=1`, but if `l[1]==1` that's another `1`, so `l[1]>=2`, which implies `l[1]` is the lone `2`. This gives `l[2]=1`, and all the remaining entries are `0`, so `l[0]=n-4`, which completes the solution.

Comment: And the language is ...?

Comment: @edc65 It looks like python. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, n≈40

```python
def plausible_suffix(l,N):
    if sum(l)>N:
        return False

    pairs = [(N-1-i,l[i]) for i in range(len(l))]

    if sum(i*x for i,x in pairs)>N:
        return False

    num_remaining = N - len(l)

    for index, desired_count in pairs:
        count = l.count(index)
        more_needed = desired_count - count
        if more_needed<0: 
            return False
        num_remaining -= more_needed
        if num_remaining<0:
            return False
    return True

plausible_func = plausible_suffix

def generate_magic(N):
    l=[0]
    while l:
        extend = False
        if plausible_func(l,N):
            if len(l)==N:
                yield l[::-1]
            else:
                extend = True
        if extend:
            l.append(0)
        else:
            while l[-1]>=N-2:
                l.pop(-1)
                if not l:raise StopIteration
            l[-1]+=1

n=40 #test parameter

if n>0:
    for x in generate_magic(n):
        print(n,x)
```

Does a breadth-first search of possible lists, filling in entries from right to left, stopping the search at a suffix if it isn't plausible, which can happen if:

- The sum of the entries in the suffix exceeds `n` (the sum for the whole list must be `n`)
- The weighted sum of `i*l[i]` in the suffix exceeds `n` (the sum for the whole list must be `n`)
- Any number appears in the suffix more times that the suffix says it should
- The number of remaining unfilled spots is too small to account for all numbers that need to appear more times.

I had original tested prefixes left to right, but that went more slowly.

The outputs up to `n=30` are:

```
4 [1, 2, 1, 0]
4 [2, 0, 2, 0]
5 [2, 1, 2, 0, 0]
7 [3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
8 [4, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
9 [5, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
10 [6, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
11 [7, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
12 [8, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
13 [9, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
14 [10, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
15 [11, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
16 [12, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
17 [13, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
18 [14, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
19 [15, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
20 [16, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
21 [17, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
22 [18, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
23 [19, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
24 [20, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
25 [21, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
26 [22, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
27 [23, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
28 [24, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
29 [25, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
30 [26, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Except for the first three lists `[1, 2, 1, 0], [2, 0, 2, 0], [2, 1, 2, 0, 0]`, there is exactly one list of each length `n>6`, and it has the form `[n-4, 2, 1, ..., 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`. This pattern persists up to at least `n=50`. I suspect it holds forever, in which case it's trivial to output a huge number of these. Even if not, a mathematical understanding on the possible solutions would greatly speed up a search.

Comment: @Ypnypn I've special-cased `n=0`. I'd missed that we're returning the result for a single `n`, not counting up `n`'s. This gets me up to `n=40`.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 15 bytes

Uses brute force by all possible sequences of len `n` and then filters.

```
f.A.eq/TkYT^UQQ
```

Full explanation coming soon.

[Try it here online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f.A.eq%2FTkYT%5EUQQ&input=4).

Comment: FYI, the OP changed the winning criterion to fastest code.

Comment: Regardless of the winning criterion, here's a 3 byte golf: ` fqm/TdQT^UQQ`

Answer (score 0):

## K, 26 bytes

```
{f@&{x~(+/x=)'!#x}'f:!x#x}
```

Like Maltysen's approach, brute force. The heart of the program is a predicate which tests whether a given vector is "magic":

```
{x~(+/x=)'!#x}
```

Build an iota vector as long as the input vector (`!#x`), count the occurrences of each digit (`(+/x=)'`) and compare the result with the input vector (`x~`). If there's a match, you have a magic sequence.

Unfortunately, this first stab seems to be pretty slow. Testing using Kona on my laptop it takes about 12 seconds to handle n=7. I need to give this a bit more thought.